# Programmable momentary switch for motorized desk desk leg with elcetronic stop

Tags: switches

We're building motorised tables with 1 leg. Currently the manufacturer can only do either:

- 2 buttons up and down switch, that need to be pressed to start the motor and pressed again to stop the motor. This can be programmed so it does not overextend or drive down too far.
- 2 buttons up and down momentary switch, that only go up or down while pressed, and stop when not pressed. But this cannot be programmed to stop before the "hard stop", which makes the gears grind before the stop.

Question: I need to source momentary switches that can be programmed so we can define the maximum extension or collapse which is before the hard stop. Our supplier isn't able to find those

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean when you write, *"I need to source momentary switches that can be programmed so we can define the maximum extension or collapse which is before the hard stop."* You earlier said that the manufacturer can provide *"2 buttons up and down switch, that need to be pressed to start the motor and pressed again to stop the motor. This can be programmed so it does not overextend or drive down too far."* So you've already got a programmable situation that works. So it seems. So why are you asking for what you already can get? Or what's the nuanced difference??? I don't get it.

Comment: i think that you do not have a good understanding of how the switches work .... the switches are not programmable ... the motor controller is programmable ... the motor controller reacts to the switch state

Comment: You need limit switches in series with the buttons, and placed so they open, and stop the motor, just before the table reaches the end-of-travel.  A common name for switches designed to be operated by things, rather than people, is "Microswitch(tm)".